# how to compute the area of 3-dim sphere directly?

Tags: calculus, integration

I want to compute the area of  3-dim sphere with radius 1 directly
and  I thought that $S^3(1) = \cup_{r}S^1(r) \times S^1(\sqrt{1-r^2})$
so the volume $Vol(S^3(1))$ should be equal to $\int_{0}^{1}Vol(S^1(r))\cdot Vol(S^1(\sqrt{1-r^2}))\,dr$, but where is it wrong?

Comment: That's a very odd formula for $S^3(1)$. Among other things, the volume terms of the factors of that formula are not independent, so why would you expect you can simply multiply them and integrate?

Comment: I don't understand. Isn't the volume $Vol(X \times Y)$ equal to $Vol(X) \times Vol(Y)$ ?

Comment: That formula is true if the Riemannian metric on $X \times Y$ is the product (in the sense of the infinitesimal Pythagorean Theorem) of the Riemannian metrics on $X$ and $Y$. But that does not hold in this case.

Comment: Could you explain it more explicitly? I'm really confused....

Answer (score 0):

It is simpler to start with volumes. Denote by $B_{n,r}$ the ball of radius $r$ in ${\mathbb R}^n$ centered at $0$. Then, according to Fubini,
$$\eqalign{{\rm vol}(B_{4,1})&=
\int_{x^2+y^2+u^2+v^2\leq 1}1\>{\rm d}(x,y,u,v)\cr  
&= \int_{B_{2,1}}\left(\int_{B_{2,\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}}}1\>{\rm d}(u,v)\right)\>{\rm d}(x,y)\cr
&=\int_{B_{2,1}}\pi(1-x^2-y^2)\>{\rm d}(x,y)\cr
&=2\pi^2\int_0^1 (1-r^2)r\>dr ={\pi^2\over2}\ ,
\cr}$$
hence ${\rm vol}(B_{4,r})={\pi^2\over2} r^4$.
It follows that
$${\rm area}(S^3)=\lim_{\epsilon\to0+}{{\rm vol}(B_{4,1+\epsilon}\setminus B_{4,1})\over\epsilon}={\pi^2\over2}\lim_{\epsilon\to0+}{(1+\epsilon)^4-1\over\epsilon}=2\pi^2\ .$$

Comment: Thank you, but I want to compute the area $S^3$ "directly" without computing the volume of 4-dim ball first....